# Dealing with big datasets in R

Tags: r, ff, r-bigmemory

I'm having a memory problem with R giving the `Can not allocate vector of size XX Gb` error message. I have a bunch of daily files (12784 days) in netcdf format giving sea surface temperature in a 1305x378 (longitude-latitude) grid. That gives 493290 points each day, decreasing to about 245000 when removing NAs (over land points).

My final objective is to build a time series for any of the 245000 points from the daily files and find the temporal trend for each point. And my idea was to build a big data frame with a point per row and a day per column (2450000x12784) so I could apply the trend calculation to any point. But then, building such data frame, the memory problem appeared, as expected.

First I tried a script I had previously used to read data and extract a three column (lon-lat-sst) dataframe by reading nc file and then melting the data. This lead to an excessive computing time when tried for a small set of days and to the memory problem. Then I tried to subset the daily files into longitudinal slices; this avoided the memory problem but the csv output files were too big and the process was very time consuming.

Another strategy I've tried without success to the moment it's been to sequentially read all the nc files and then extract all the daily values for each point and find the trend. Then I would only need to save a single 245000 points dataframe. But I think this would be time consuming and not the proper R way.

I have been reading about `big.memory` and `ff` packages to try to declare big.matrix or a 3D array (1305 x 378 x 12784) but had not success by now.

What would be the appropriate strategy to face the problem?

1. Extract single point time series to calculate individual trends and populate a smaller dataframe
2. Subset daily files in slices to avoid the memory problem but end with a lot of dataframes/files
3. Try to solve the memory problem with bigmemory or ff packages

Thanks in advance for your help

**EDIT 1**
Add code to fill the matrix

```
library(stringr)
library(ncdf4)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

# paths
ruta_datos<-"/home/meteo/PROJECTES/VERSUS/CMEMS/DATA/SST/"
ruta_treball<-"/home/meteo/PROJECTES/VERSUS/CMEMS/TREBALL/"
setwd(ruta_treball)

sst_data_full <- function(inputfile) {

  sstFile <- nc_open(inputfile)
  sst_read <- list()

  sst_read$lon <- ncvar_get(sstFile, "lon")
  sst_read$lats <- ncvar_get(sstFile, "lat")
  sst_read$sst <- ncvar_get(sstFile, "analysed_sst")

  nc_close(sstFile)

  sst_read
}

melt_sst <- function(L) {
  dimnames(L$sst) <- list(lon = L$lon, lat = L$lats)
  sst_read <- melt(L$sst, value.name = "sst")
}

# One month list file: This ends with a df of 245855 rows x 33 columns
files <- list.files(path = ruta_datos, pattern = "SST-CMEMS-198201")

sst.out=data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(files) ) { 
  sst<-sst_data_full(paste0(ruta_datos,files[i],sep=""))
  msst <- melt_sst(sst)
  msst<-subset(msst, !is.na(msst$sst))

  if ( i == 1 ) {
  sst.out<-msst
  } else {
  sst.out<-cbind(sst.out,msst$sst)
  }

}
```

**EDIT 2**
Code used in a previous (smaller) data frame to calculate temporal trend. Original data was a matrix of temporal series, being each column a series.

```
library(forecast)

data<-read.csv(....)

for (i in 2:length(data)){

var<-paste("V",i,sep="")
ff<-data$fecha
valor<-data[,i]  
datos2<-as.data.frame(cbind(data$fecha,valor))
datos.ts<-ts(datos2$valor, frequency = 365)

datos.stl <- stl(datos.ts,s.window = 365)

datos.tslm<-tslm(datos.ts ~ trend)

summary(datos.tslm)

output[i-1]<-datos.tslm$coefficients[2]

}
```

fecha is date variable name

**EDIT 2**
Working code from F. Privé answer

```
library(bigmemory)

tmp <- sst_data_full(paste0(ruta_datos,files[1],sep=""))

library(bigstatsr)
mat <- FBM(length(tmp$sst), length(files),backingfile = "/home/meteo/PROJECTES/VERSUS/CMEMS/TREBALL" )

for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  mat[, i] <- sst_data_full(paste0(ruta_datos,files[i],sep=""))$sst
}
```

With this code a big matrix was created

```
dim(mat)
[1] 493290  12783
mat[1,1]
[1] 293.05
mat[1,1:10]
[1] 293.05 293.06 292.98 292.96 292.96 293.00 292.97 292.99 292.89 292.97
ncol(mat)
[1] 12783
nrow(mat)
[1] 493290
```

Comment: How about if you put all your data in a proper database and query from there?

Comment: This would probably run but I only have basic knowledge of databases and I also have a deadline, if possible I prefer an R based solution. Thanks.

Comment: This could be done with a `big.matrix` (bigmemory) or `FBM` (bigstatsr) of size (1305x378) x 12784 (47GB on disk). You should fill it by column (each day). But what you are interested in is each row, you then can transpose it (e.g. with `big_transpose`) and then operate on each column (each point).

Comment: Hi @F.Privé from bigmemory I can see rows and columns can be set `big.matrix(nrow, ncol, type = "integer", init = 0, dimnames = NULL)` but how do I add the third dimension, maybe a list?

Comment: I have tried `kk<-as.big.matrix(array(0,dim=c(1305, 378, 12784)))` but it gives the allocation error for the `47.0 Gb` vector

Comment: Create an object by specifying only dimensions (not initialized). With `big.matrix` or `FBM`. And use `1305 * 378` for the first dimension.

Comment: @pacomet Please provide the code you tried to fill the matrix. And also the code to summarize each row in only on value per row.

Comment: @F.Privé I'll be out of office for some days, will post next week. Thanks

Comment: Hi @F.Privé added first attempt code for an example matrix for just a month of daily data (31 days) without big.memory. Could not properly try bigmemory because of the allocation error

Comment: @pacomet I need some data (an example file?) to be able to run your code.

Comment: @F.Privé You can find ten daily data files for January 1982 at this [dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mreb98nyjvty6ib/AABwpreLY2AwJci94ZUXLoQYa?dl=0)

Comment: Hi @F.Privé Could you test the data and code? Thanks

Comment: @pacomet I'm having trouble installing package **ncdf4** on CentOS 7

Comment: @pacomet A `FBM` is similar to a `big.matrix` but isn't one. So that you don't need **bigmemory** here.

Comment: @F.Privé Is it possible to use `complete.cases` with a `big.matrix` to remove rows that only contain NA?

Comment: @pacomet Nop, you'll have to implement it yourself. Moreover, you should use indices as a parameter of the algorithms you use in order to subset a FBM, not create (copy) another one each time you want to use subsetting.

Comment: @F.Privé Well, I'll try to dump final trend to a smaller data frame (all rows but 1 single column) and then remove NAs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to your read data in a Filebacked Big Matrix (FBM), you can do

```
files <- list.files(path = "SST-CMEMS", pattern = "SST-CMEMS-198201*",
                    full.names = TRUE)

tmp <- sst_data_full(files[1])

library(bigstatsr)
mat <- FBM(length(tmp$sst), length(files))

for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  mat[, i] <- sst_data_full(files[i])$sst
}
```

Comment: It seems it has worked fine for the first month creating a matrix of 493290 rows and 31 columns, all points/rows for a month/column. Gonna try for the full set, 35 years.

Comment: Hi @F.Privé There is a problem with the matrix, I think the backing file is located in /tmp in my system but there is not enough free space. Can it be moved to /home where there is plenty of disk space?

Comment: @pacomet Yeap, there is a parameter for that.

Comment: I used backingfile parameter and it works fine, see code in the question edit